# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: missing block number for head header hash

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, nodes, ethereum-classic

I didn't check on the running Geth instance and when I executed a function that logs everything in the Blockchain, I had an error that the port I was listening to wasn't responding. I figured out that there wasn't enough space in my storage so I upgraded it. After I upgraded the storage, I've been seeing this error when I try to sync my node:

`Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: missing block number for head header hash`

I couldn't resolve it nor can I use `geth attach`. Geth instantly terminates after displaying that error. Is resyncing the only way to solve this? I've also read that after resyncing, the problem will still persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. The solution was update to the [newest geth version](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/), remove the old chain data `geth removedb` and resync the chain `geth --fast --cache=1024`