# Geth interface panic after weeks of being in sync

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, geth-debugging

After weeks of being in sync and working fine, my Geth just stopped. Upon restart, what started as a long hang on FS Sync Time (repeat output with different values, no further movement beyond allocation of cache and file handles), turned into a panic on latest launch:

```
INFO [03-17|12:07:14.213] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
WARN [03-17|12:07:15.325] Head block missing, resetting chain      hash=5414aa…aaf1f5
WARN [03-17|12:07:15.325] Rewinding blockchain                     target=0
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not *types.Block

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).CurrentBlock(...)
        /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:359
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).SetHead(0x400c4aa000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:302 +0x8a0
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).ResetWithGenesisBlock(0x400c4aa000, 0x40002d4120, 0x0, 0x0)
```

I am now unable to progress past this point.

Comment: is your geth client up to date?

Comment: Yes, 1.8.23 stable.

Answer (score 0):

`Solution: remove ethereum files, and start geth again.`

Ethereum Geth use "fast" option defaultly.

fast option defaulty have `only 10,000 lastest blocks.`

If the difference between `the lastest block` in public Ethereum and `your lastest block on storage` is over 10,000. `"Head block missing" occurs.`

Because fast option only needs to download recent 10,000 blocks and state.

If difference is big, users should download more than 10,000 blocks.

"Downloading more than 10,000 blocks" wastes user's resource.

Comment: I am running full nodes and have the whole 171GB of chaindata required. Starting from scratch is not an option because it would take another week to get in sync.

Comment: what's your setup specs? I did a full, fast sync in 30 hours & 40 minutes

Comment: NanoPC-T4. It's an experiment in nodes on microcomputers: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/alnmxn/ethereum_on_arm_geth_and_parity_clients_update/

Comment: Yes, but there is no solution except for removing files. Archive node has the whole 2TB.

Comment: Not sure what archive nodes have to do with anything, I'm running full nodes. Anyway, deleting everything is obviously not acceptable, not just in my case but in general. Not being able to continue from a non-zero block would make geth utterly broken software at this point in Ethereum's lifespan. I'm sure it's not that badly designed, otherwise no one would be running nodes.

Comment: fast sync process, 1) download (recent -10000) block's state. and 2) sequentially download next block and execute transactions and update state... repeat 10,000 times.

Comment: `Head block missing` will not happen in archive node.

Comment: (other answer)[https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41882/fatal-error-starting-protocol-stack-missing-block-number-for-head-header-hash?rq=1] said `geth removedb` and `geth --fast --cache=1024`

Comment: Like I said, full resync isn't an option